# Have machine learning techniques been used to play outdoor games, like cricket or badminton?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, game-ai

Have machine learning techniques been used to play outdoor games, like cricket or badminton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

A group of Chinese college students and teachers made a [robot that plays badminton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRVdwINXpMI).  I am sure someone will make a robot that can play cricket and other outside games.

[image]

Although not an outdoor game, [Omron made a robot named Forpheus that plays ping pong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXyKLDNzGGI).  There is also a [robot that plays the sport of curling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARbNmCu04Ko).

There is an annual event called the [RoboCup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9uFIBGSkMg) where robot teams compete in indoor soccer on a scaled down level.  They don't look like they will be beating humans in the next couple of years but it is interesting to watch.  Their web site is: http://www.robocup.org/

[image]

There are a few challenges that remain to be resolved for robots to play humans in sports.  The biggest one is self-contained power that will last long enough to play a game.  It takes a lot of power to move a human scaled robot and run its electronics, sensors, and computers.  Other challenges are dexterity and agility.  There have been some advances in these areas as this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vIT2da6N_o) shows.